# Powershell - last function runs correctly, individually fine,no errors, just incorrect output for the first 2 functions

Tags: function, powershell, foreach

Basically this code is supposed to go through a server list and for each server run 3 functions. one to list local users, one for administrators, and one for listing RDP users. The script seems to run fine individually, but when I add them all together, the first two give me results, just not the expected results. Any ideas would be groovy. I've listed the contents of each function at the end.

```
    $ServerList = Get-Content "ServerList.txt"

    foreach ($i in $ServerList){

    write-host ("                                                   ",$i)
    write-host "     
                  Local Users
    "
    get-local $i
    write-host "     
                  Administrator Users
    "
    get-localadmin $i
    write-host "
                  RDP Users
    "
    get-rdp $i
     }
     write-host "                                                                   COMPLETED"

     function get-local {  
     param ($strcomputer)  

     $admins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $strcomputer   
     $admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"users"'}  

     $admins |% {  
     $_.partcomponent –match “.+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$” > $nul  
     $matches[1].trim('"') + “\” + $matches[2].trim('"')  
     }  
     }

     function get-localadmin {  
     param ($strcomputer)  

     $admins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $strcomputer   
     $admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'}  

     $admins |% {  
     $_.partcomponent –match “.+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$” > $nul  
     $matches[1].trim('"') + “\” + $matches[2].trim('"')  
     }  
     }

     function get-rdp {  
     param ($strcomputer)  

     $admins = Gwmi win32_groupuser –computer $strcomputer   
     $admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Remote Desktop Users"'}  

     $admins |% {  
     $_.partcomponent –match “.+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$” > $nul  
     $matches[1].trim('"') + “\” + $matches[2].trim('"')  
     }  
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the expected output? When I run the functions individually or together, they work the same. When I run through your loop, it also works fine. It shows the local users, the local admins, and remote desktop users members (if any)

Cleaned output

```
              Local Users

PC1\INTERACTIVE
PC1\Authenticated Users
PC1\Domain Users
PC1\test
 
              Administrator Users

PC1\Administrator
PC1\someuser
DOMAIN\Domain Admins
DOMAIN\doug

              RDP Users

PC1\test
```

If you're just wanting to list local users, you can use

```
Get-LocalUser
```

For Local admin, you can use

```
Get-LocalGroup "administrators" | Get-LocalGroupMember
```

For RDP users

```
Get-LocalGroup "Remote Desktop Users" | Get-LocalGroupMember
```

Edit: To answer the question "shouldn't "administrator" be listed as a local user?" from your comment. No. The Get-Local function is pulling members of the "Users" local group. The same list is created by running

```
Get-LocalGroup Users | Get-LocalGroupMember
```

See my alternative command recommendation if you want to simplify your code. The functions seem dated as well as overcomplicated.

Comment: huh. well maybe I buggered it somehow. let me do a test

Comment: shouldn't "administrator" be listed as a local user?

Comment: Where did you get those functions? They are strictly pulling groups and then filtering users based on group membership. Administrator would be listed in any of the three if it is a member of any of those groups.

Comment: I get this error using your commands: Get-LocalGroupMember : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command
does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline
input.

Comment: and : Get-LocalUser : User user was not found.

Comment: If there is no output for get-localuser, then there is nothing to pipe to get-localgroupmember. The error message makes me think you typed get-localuser user